# transferring data by get, php in the url and security

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the first question and I need your help.

I transfer form data from first page using header location method in php to second page.

On the second page I accept the data using get.

Now here the url of 2nd page, after the data is sent (i.e. form is submitted)

http://mydomain.com/site1/form1_conf.php?id=123

When user is on second page, the data on second page is being displayed according the id number from the mysql database.

Now the problem is that when the user is on second page and he changes the number (for ex. 123 to say 78) the data of id=78, from the database is displayed, which is no good.

How can I stop that?

Please Note: I can't use post, nor can I use sessions.

EDITE:

php code on first page, to transfer to second page:

```
// after all validations are okay
$insert = //insert into database
$result = mysql_query($insert);
if($result)
{
echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
$lastInsertedId =  mysql_insert_id();
header('Location:form1_conf.php?id='.$lastInsertedId); //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE
}
else
{
$message = "The data cannot be inserted.";
$message .= "<br />" . mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: you can't control what number a user sends over. a post can be be trivially forged. Your only option is to use server-side storage to keep that number, e.g. sessions, database, file-on-drive, etc...

Comment: _"I can't use POST, nor sessions"_ and pray, why not? GET is insecure. Full-stop. There's no _real_ way to be sure that the data in the url hasn't been messed with. You can mess around by writing a file to disk with the number, using hashes with the IP of the client, timestamt and the number in question, but basically, you're just going to make it harder on yourself

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem bullshit, read my answer. Just sign with a hash and the URL is protected from all tampering. This is precisely how banking APIs, PayPal etc. work.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: mind your language... besides, though highly unlikely, hash collisions never 100% impossible. Hence, even your `sha1` hash is not 100% secure, only 99.999999...%. Also: what is `$id` assigned when you compare the hashes? the client could've sent a valid request for id 123, or id = 12. If get var id were constant, there would be no need for an uri param

Comment: SHA1 is 160-bits, so 1,4615016373309029182036848327163e+48 options. That makes it approximately 99.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999% safe from accidental collisions. As for the validation - I'm assuming the postback validates that the client can access id 123. Therefore the request to 123 is repeatable, cacheable and storable. If this isn't the case adding a timestamp to the parameters and the hash to timebomb the URL's validity is trivial.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem i cant use sessions because if a user opens multiple tabs, session is fu**ed up. I cant use post because i am already posting the form data to same page. so i can only transfer via header location method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not with the URLs: to a power user changing cookies or POST-variables is as trivial as editing GET-variables for a regular user. You'll need some way to 'sign' the requests as being valid.

Easiest to do this is with a "pre-shared key", which you use with one-way hashes to validate requests.

Redirector:

```
$newURL = '/newpage?id='.$id.'&hash='.sha1('mypresharedkey'.$id);
header('HTTP/1.1 303 See other');
header('Location: '.$newURL);
die;
```

The other page:

```
$idToShow = $_GET['id'];
$hash = sha1('mypresharedkey'.$id);
if($hash != $_GET['hash'])
  die("Tssss, don't play with the address bar!");
else
  RenderThePage();
```

This ensures end users can only access pages they've been allowed to by the submit.

---

For your specific code:

```
...all prior code
$lastInsertedId = mysql_insert_id();
$timestamp = time();
header('Location:form1_conf.php?'.http_build_query([
      'id' => $lastInsertedId,
      'time' => $timestamp,
      'hash' => sha1('some-generated-key'.$timestamp.$lastInsertedId)
]);
```

In the other page, including a timebomb if you want (otherwise just comment it out):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$time = $_GET['time'];
if($_GET['hash'] != sha1('some-generated-key'.$time.$id))
  die('URL was tampered with');
if(time() - $time > 300)
  die('URL was only valid for 5 minutes');
```

Comment: this seems to be a perfect solution, but in order to implement it i need more help.. please stay here for some more time, let me analyse the situation and i want to ask more questions..

Comment: @neo I made a similar thing, maybe easier to use. See in my answer below.

Comment: please check the edit in the question.. search for these words. please tell how to implement your solution to that line?
look for line with this data, THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE

Comment: wow. I love you man. by the way.. where can i find the link to learn and implement this "some-generated-key"

Comment: It's just a [Shared Secret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_secret), a basic concept of cryptography, also known as a Pre-Shared Key or PSK. You can replace it with for example a generated password, or randomly hammer your keyboard until it's 50 characters or more - as long as both pages use the same PSK this'll work.

Comment: it is giving me two syntax errors, one on line of header location and 2nd on line of ]);

Comment: sorry to say but it is generating error in dreamweaver as i mentioned earlier

Comment: I'm using short array syntax in that line, that's PHP 5.4 or only - so update your webserver. Meanwhile you can replace the `[...]` syntax with `array(...)` for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You need to track the user and the id that they have in your database to make sure that they haven't changed the number.  So when you get the information via the `GET` you make sure that it is legit.

Users can change the id or even attempt to go directly to that page via the url.  So you need some sort of server-side check to verify that it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could complicate this "cheating" a bit, if you didn't pass the ID number directly, but somehow encrypted it.

Let's say, you define a salt:

```
define(SALT, 'long weird salt with special characters etc.');
```

Here comes the first part you want:

```
$lastInsertedId = mysql_insert_id();

$querytag = base64_encode($lastInsertedId); // just to make it less readable
$checksum = md5($querytag . SALT); // and make a hash

header('Location:form1_conf.php?id=' . $querytag . '&checksum=' . $checksum);
```

At the beginning of form1_conf.php, you put this:

```
$encodedId = $_GET['id'];
$oldChecksum = $_GET['checksum'];

$newChecksum = md5($encodedId . SALT);

$id = base64_decode($encodedId);

if($newChecksum != $oldChecksum) {
    die('You Are Cheating!');
}

... do something with the $id ...
```

The point is that since you add SALT to the hash, some user can't simply use md5 on a changed ID, because he's missing the SALT you used.

It'd be even better if the salt wasn't the same every time.

Comment: friend, please check the updated question, i added php code to transfer the value from first page. also id is not just this one, it is server generated and auto incremented.. how can i implement your solution there?

Answer (score 0):

You should never trust the url because there is always a way to manipulate the data.

So you should do validation after retreiving the data. If the result does not fit you: for example the loggedin user with the ID = 1 requests the settings page from the userid = 3 you do not show the result.

```
<?php
    $userID = $_GET['id'];
    if($userID != $expectedResult)
    {
        //show errormessage, redirect or show the page with the users data
    }

?>
```

Comment: He can't use sessions.

Comment: Well i did not see that. Thx for the hint.